Executing 3 commands in a container
This command works
az containerapp exec --name weather-scrapy-shell --resource-group rg-SportsAzureFunctionsContainer --container weather-scrapy-shell --command "/bin/sh"

This command connects me to the container and I can manually run
cd /app/Scrapy/Scrapy
then 
scrapy crawl WeatherData -a Week=week -a Year=2023 -a Day=135

That works.
I am trying to automate this process so I need to connect to the shell and also run the 2 commands listed above so this task can be automated and scripted.
Is there a way to initiate a container and with one command execute all 3 commands in the shell at once?
az containerapp exec --name weather-scrapy-shell --resource-group rg-SportsAzureFunctionsContainer --container weather-scrapy-shell --command "/bin/sh -c 'cd /app/Scrapy/Scrapy && scrapy crawl WeatherData -a Week=week -a Year=2023 -a Day=135'"

here is the command output
INFO: Successfully connected to container: 'weather-scrapy-shell'. [ Revision: 'weather-scrapy-shell--naa89wx', Replica: 'weather-scrapy-shell--naa89wx-5cf5697597-4lnmx']
/app/Scrapy/Scrapy: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
INFO: received success status from cluster

The error states there is a missing quote but I have tried this variation and got same error
az containerapp exec --name nflweather-scrapy-shell --resource-group rg-SportsAzureFunctionsContainer --container weather-scrapy-shell --command "/bin/sh -c 'cd /app/Scrapy/Scrapy' &&  'scrapy crawl WeatherData -a Week=week -a Year=2023 -a Day=135'"

This variation does not fail. Output says it was successful but it does not execute the script and does not generate any data.
az containerapp exec --name weather-scrapy-shell --resource-group rg-SportsAzureFunctionsContainer --container weather-scrapy-shell --command "/bin/sh -c cd /app/Scrapy/Scrapy &&  scrapy crawl WeatherData -a Week=week -a Year=2023 -a Day=135"

My Objective is to be able to to connect and run all 3 commands. IS there another way if this apporach is incorrect?

Hi Olaf these are powershell commands. I beleive there may be a syntax error in powershell.

OK my apologies I assumed they where Powershell commands because I execute them in powershell on my local machine. As you wish I have removed powershell. Thank you for the education.

What is the main command in the container?  Can you connect it to some sort of HTTP service or job queue, so that you don't need to use an "exec" debugging command to trigger this work?

Hi, David my objective is to run the scrapy command to pull weather data. The only way I know how to exectue the command to pull weather data is the way I am doing it. I am open to doing it differently if possible. This container reside in Azure cloud and I am running it on my local VScode. My secondary objective is to create a script that I can schedule so I can automate this process. Also I am not sure I understand your question about the main command in t he container.

@triplee these are not the same as these are Azure CLI commands. I did learn a few things from that post. I did try ; and it still did not work.
